# No Exception handle in jSerialComm?

Tags: java, serial-port

I am using the jSerialComm library to communicate to and from the SerialPort. I have written a SerialDataListener to read the bytes with an overridden serialEvent method that looks like this:

```
@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    if (event.getEventType() != SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE) return;
    int numBytesAvailable = serialPort.bytesAvailable();
    if (numBytesAvailable < 0) {
        logger.error("Port is not open.. returning without any action");
        return;
    }
    byte[] newData = new byte[numBytesAvailable];
    int readData = serialPort.readBytes(newData, numBytesAvailable);
    for (int i = 0; i < numBytesAvailable; i++) {
        byte b = newData[i];
        logger.info("Starting new response");
        response = new Response();
        response.addByte(b);
    }
}
```

Now, if I do receive data and the subsequent code gets into a NUllPointerException somehow (one example being that the response's constructor is invoked and throws an NPE), then the SerialPort has been programmed inside the library's SerialPort class to

1. stop listening and
2. Swallow the exception
3. As a consequence of 1 and 2, no more data arriving on the SerialPort can be processed. There is neither an exposed API to see if the listener is stopped and restart it. I can neither take any action like reopening the SerialPort.

Here is that piece of code:

```
//Line 895 of the class SerialPort) (from dependency:  com.fazecast:jSerialComm:1.3.11).

while (isListening && isOpened) { try { waitForSerialEvent(); } catch (NullPointerException e) { isListening = false; } }
```

Here are the questions:

1. Why was the exception swallowed and listening stopped inside the library? Are there any design reasons?
2. The SerialPort class itself is `final` and hence writing my own implementation of the class to replace the swallow is out of question. How do I proceed? Apart from this issue, jSerialComm appears to satisfy most other use cases decently well, so I may not migrate from it anytime soon.
3. One way is to catch it myself and do the handling. But I do not want to do it unless the answer for Q1 is clear. I have tried to investigate but not found any practical reasons for disabling the listening and not announcing the exception.
4. Why just a NPE, other exceptions could arise too. So then at least, I will have to handle the exceptions myself. Is this approach of my own handlers correct then?

TIA
Rahul

Comment: 1. Update: Verified in com.fazecast:jSerialComm:2.0.2. Same code in SerialPort:Line 885
2. For now, put a try catch on the code and it at least does not allow the SerialPort to stop listening. But I still suspect the approach is just a hack!

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Why was the exception swallowed and listening stopped inside the library? Are there any design reasons?

You would need to ask the author of the code.

However, it does seem to be intentional, since the `waitForSerialEvent` is declared as `throws NullPointerException`.

If I were you, I would dig deeper into where the NPEs are thrown and why.  Modify the code to print a stacktrace instead of just squashing the exception entirely.  It could be a "hack" workaround, or there could be a legitimate reason for doing this.

If we make the assumption that the client's listener code could throw an NPE, then in my view it is a mistake for the event thread to assume that all NPEs can be squashed.

But looking at the code, I can also see places where NPE's are being thrown deliberately to (apparently) signal there is an error; e.g. in the `read` methods in `SerialPortInputStream`.  So it is not clear to me that the NPEs should be squashed at all.

> 2) The SerialPort class itself is final and hence writing my own implementation of the class to replace the swallow is out of question. How do I proceed?

The code is on GitHub, so you *could* fork the repository, develop a patch and submit a pull request.

> 4) Why just a NPE, other exceptions could arise too. So then at least, I will have to handle the exceptions myself. Is this approach of my own handlers correct then?

Good question.

---

But really, all of these questions are best addressed to the author of the code.  He does seem to respond to questions posted as issues ... if they are pertinent.